# How to convert 85 rows in to one rows in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a file, which has 310 blocks. And each of the blocks has 85 rows. Every row has ten numbers except for the last row.

I need to do some data process. I want to convert these blocks to 310 rows. So that is one rows for each block.

I know I can write this:

B(1,:)=[a(1,:),a(2,:),a(3,:)] to do the row combine job, but now I need to combine 85 rows, how can I write B(1,:)=[a(1,:),a(2,:),a(3,:),...,a(85,1:4)] in Matlab?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To linearise a matrix, you can use `(:)`. To get the right order, its necessary to transpose fist.

```
h=a.'
B(1,:)=h(:)
```

To get everything up to `a(85,4)`

```
h=a.'
B(1,:)=h(1:sub2ind(size(h),4,85))
```

sub2ind transforms the matrix index to a linear index (single number).

Comment: As usual, be careful with using `'` instead of `.'`, unless you want to conjugate complex values